# error Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.context.DelegatingApplicationListener

Tags: java, xml, spring, oauth, spring-java-config

i want try to mix between xml based and java based in my resource server using spring oauth2

but i got this error

```html
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/context/DelegatingApplicationListener
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
 at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:140)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:220)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:391)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:205)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:287)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:225)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:632)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:802)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:559)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1399)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
 at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
 at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
 at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1500)
 at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:849)
 at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:351)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.context.DelegatingApplicationListener
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
 ... 49 more
```

this is my web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>nls</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/config/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/config/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <filter>
          <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
          <filter-class>com.noi.nls.sec.ResponseCorsFilter</filter-class>
      </filter>
      <filter-mapping>
          <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>

    
    <!--Spring Security--> 
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <!--    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>-->
</web-app>
```

my applicationContext.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.1.xsd"> 
    

    
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <import resource="classpath*:config/spring-db.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath*:config/spring-security-min.xml"/>

</beans>
```

and my spring-security-min.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
             xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd">  
    
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.noi.nls.sec" />
  
  </beans:beans>
```

any help, where is my wrong... :)

Comment: Did you check if you have that class in the classpath? Are you using maven for dependencies or manually copying jars?

Comment: look into classpath for spring-security-core jar file.

Comment: @HarshPoddar : iam using maven for dependecies. this error is occured if using this <import resource="classpath*:config/spring-security-min.xml"/> if not my app will run properly.

Comment: @BhavinPanchani: yes it's already in there..

Comment: Have you added dependency for `groupId: org.springframework.security` and `artifactId: spring-security-core` in your pom? Is the version compatible with the version of spring mvc you are using?

Comment: <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</versiion>
<type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

and for version spring-webmvc is 3.2.11.RELEASE

but i thinks it should be ok, because in my previous project authorization server i used it and it work.

Answer (score 1):

ah my bad.

after posting a comment i know that my version of spring-security-config and spring-security-core is not same version..

i got to fix that...

@ Harsh Poddar: thanks for your hints.